# PHP Ajax onkeyup doesn't work on my Switch case website

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, switch-statement, onkeyup

I have a website where I use php case and include as website.
So depending on the ?page="" result I get it includes a new website.

Example: www.test.come/?page=test.

The example I use to test the PHP and Ajax onkeyup function is this one:

**Test.php**

```
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form> 
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
```

**gethint.php**

```
<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
$a[] = "Cinderella";
$a[] = "Fiona";
$a[] = "Gunda";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

So if my www.test.com/?page=test it will include the Test.php on my website.

Everything on Test.php is uploaded on the website and looks great but when I type in the letter a for example in the box then the name Anna is supposed to pop up but it doesn't.

but if I type the page www.test.com/include/Test.php where the Test.php file exist it works perfectly.

Here is the code that I use to switch between different pages:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["page"])){
    $page = $_GET["page"];
} else {
$page = "News";
}
```

I think this could be the biggest reason why this doesn't work, but then I need an explanation for why and if there is something I can do to make it work.

I can give you a full example on all my code, but that will become a WALL of TEXT, so I thought saving you all time but shorting it up. If you need the full code to figure the issue out then I will help you with it.

Thank you very much for taking time to read this and trying to solve it.

Best regards
Simon

Comment: Where is `onclick` in your code? Your question is about `onkeyup`.

Comment: My bad, I will change it. but is it really such a big difference between onclick and onkeyup on my issue? But once again, sorry. I will change.

Comment: It confused me for a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the AJAX call to use an absolute path for `gethint.php`. Otherwise it will look for it in the same folder as the page that's making the AJAX call.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "/include/gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
```

Comment: oh god, I thought it wasn't necessary because both files were already in the same file.... Thank you very much for teaching me!